# VB Script to click a button in a website for every 30 seconds with refresh

Tags: vbscript

How to to write a VB Script, which will open a particular url and click a button in that website for every 30 seconds, and also refresh the page if possible.
You help will be appreciated.

I have written the following script:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
IE.Navigate "some url" 
IE.Visible = True 
Document.All("spin").Click()
```

I have problem with selecting the button to be clicked. Is this the correct script.

Comment: And how can I implement my semi-smooth newton method for bilinear basis elements?

Comment: @Malloc bilinear...!!! :o
I wanted to use this for a game to spin the lucky draw spinner, I don't have any other intentions and I don't know also...

Comment: That was just a joke, what I meant to say was: SO is not a free code factory. Try to solve your problem yourself first and then ask, when you run into problems.

Comment: @Malloc okay, I have updated my question, hope now it stands for SO question.

Comment: That's better, removed downvote. :)

Comment: @Jahnavi, you should add `Do While IE.ReadyState < 4: WScript.Sleep 10: Loop` after `Navigate` to avoid some errors caused page not ready, and try this one to click `IE.Document.GetElementById("spin").Click`.